# Should we use sql server spatial data for a simple lat and long scenario?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I am responsible of optimizing the performance of a query that uses geographical data to fetch all the POI within a certain area (the view port of user which is a rectangular area).

Right now we save each point as  a pair of Latitude and Longitude fields in our database and use a simple BETWEEN keyword in our WHERE clause to see if a point is in a certain rectangular area.

I didn't know anything about Sql Server Spatial Data until recently and now that I am reading about it, I start thinking what could be the benefits of using this system instead of our simple one and does it worth it for us to switch to this system or not ?

I should mention that performance is our priority and the query should be super fast.

Comment: The real question is: Do you see any features that would improve the system as is? You're the one who should know if you benefit from changing the system, really...

Comment: Since I am new to this system I thought maybe experience developers could direct me in right direction .

Comment: Unless you're having problems, it's a case of *it is isn't broken, don't fix it*. I'm assuming that you're using Pythagorean theorem, much similar to something we use to find rows within a radius of a given distance. The spatial functions offered by SQL Server, however powerful, I have found if not used correctly can cause horrid performance issues.

Comment: @JohnnyBell Good Piece of Advice :) thanks